# how to know the subscribed topics in mqtt

Tags: java, mqtt, subscription

I am currently using apollo broker and a java program to connect to that broker and subscribe to some topics but before subscribing I want to check what are the topics that I have already subscribed in my previous connections.

Is there some way to do it in java and if yes how and using which library?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is up to the application to keep track of what topics it has subscribed to.

Comment: No, don't confuse a protocol spec with a implementation. But there is nothing in the spec about querying what topics have been subscribed to and I am unaware of any libraries that would track it for you. It is the applications responsibility to remember what it has asked for